# Cakephp 3 Cache::deleteMany() wild card matching?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

Is there a way to use the use the Cache::deleteMany() function to delete cache files based on a wild card.

For example I want to delete a cache file called `posts_2_20160801` where the first number is the user_id and the number string is a date. So this cache file contains all the posts by a user before the given date for pagination.

So I want to be able to delete cache files for the user_id. Since the dates could be almost anything I need a wildcard.

Something like `Cache::deleteMany(['posts_2*']);`

Is there a way to do this or am I thinking of this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about memcached, but File and Redis engines does not support this method of deleting caches.

My solution was to make a class that extends the desired cache engine class of Cake (like `RedisEngine` or `FileEngine`) and override the `deleteMany` function so when a string is passed instead of an array, it does a wildcard search and returns all the keys, then passes the returned array of the keys to the parent function.

I know that it's possible for `File` engine and `Redis` engine with a painful amount of coding and it must be done very carefully.